# How to show post based on id in url with PHP

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting, mysqli, routes

I'm building a simple page where I list all posts on.
I'm a bit stuck because it's some time ago I made something like this.

I want to show the specific post when clicking the link. Here's an image of what I mean:

[image: page]

The blue 'title' is a url.
I don't know how to link this to another page, where the post with the id in the url is shown.

My link looks like this:

```
<a class="posts" href="http://example.com/blog/<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['titel']; ?></a>
```

This obviously gives a 'Not Found' error message.

How can I do this? It's kinda hard, because it's some time ago I worked with this.

NOTE: I am using a .htaccess file to delete the .php extension from the url.

My urls look like:

> http://example.com/home/blog

etc.

Comment: Look at your .htaccess. It is probably taking the ID and mapping that in a query string

Comment: Actually my problem is, that I don't know how to show the specific post, when I clicked the link.

Comment: "select * from posts where id='".$_GET['id']."'"

Comment: We would need to see what you're doing in that htaccess before we can answer that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^blog/([^/\.]+)/?$ blog.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Here, assuming your blog.php takes $_GET['id'], having the above in your .htaccess will route 
/blog/69 to blog.php?id=69